# Data Structure for word suggestions from a text file

Tags: algorithm, prefix, trie, suffix

Problem: We are given a text file containing many lines of text. Now the user will input a few letters and we have to give an autocomplete suggestion based on the text in the file we are given.
Let's say the file contains `computer science is fun. computer engineering is awesome`.
Now if the user types`com` we need to give as suggestion `computer science` and `computer engineering`.  If the user types `is` the suggestion should be `fun` and `awesome`. The user can input any word that might or might not be in the text file. If the word is not in the file there should be no suggestion.

What would be the best data structure for this problem.
I know that we can build a trie but with that we might only be able to suggest `computer` when the user types `com`.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: The question isn't what data structure but how you model your data. You can build an character nGram model to solve this problem.

Comment: What if your trie contained not single words but digrams?

Answer (score 1):

Preparation:

1. Read all the lines of the text file as an array of string
2. Sort lexicographically this array

Query:

1. Get the [lower bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) index given the input string: `first`
2. Increase the value of the last character of your input string by 1 (if not at its max value) and get the [lower bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) index, `last`, for this new input string. If your last character cannot incremented, use the index one past the end of your arrray.

All the possible suggestions are in the sorted array between these two bounds *not including the last index*: `[first, last)`.

If there are too many suggestions, you can filter by only suggesting the 3 shortest suggestions, or sort by statistical frequencies.

You can also print the number of suggestions instead of suggesting them. Similar to the way google tells you how many pages match your query. And then only suggest strings when the number of matches is manageable by your UI.

Comment: this sounds good but I if the user types `is` the suggestion should be `fun` and `awesome`. Don't think that would work with this solution.

Comment: @KaushalShah Well, you didn't specify that in your question :)

Comment: @KaushalShah So according to your wording, typing: `is` should suggest only end of sentences that follows `is`. We should not suggest the whole sentence that include the word `is`. Am I right ?